# Problem with hyperref and amsmath

Tags: hyperref, amsmath

I was running into trouble with hyperref when labeling propositions in the appendix.  It would get confused between Proposition 1 (in the main body of the article) and Proposition A.1 (in Appendix A).  I am still interested in figuring this out.

But the more pressing issue is that I reinstalled hyperref following the instructions on the package website.  I now run into much more serious issues.  In fact, the following short example returns an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1 + 1 = 2 \label{h1} 
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{h1}.
\end{document}
```

This is the error I get when compiling:

> ./test.tex:8: Undefined control sequence.
>   \hyper@link@ [#1]#2#3#4->\ltx@ifempty 
>                                        {#4}{\Hy@Warning {Suppressing empty li...
>   l.8 Equation \eqref{h1}
>                         .
>   ?
>
> Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 8.

(The latex file is called test.tex.)

Thanks in advance for your help, which I really need!

Comment: No problem here using Lubuntu 11.10 with TeXlive 2011.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) No problem here with MikTeX 2.9

Comment: You should be more specific. With MikTeX 2.8 compiled without errors.

Comment: It is probable that your versions of amsmath and hyperref are incompatible. As someone who recently went down this road, trust me, it's better to completely reinstall everything if you need newer versions of packages.

Comment: if you can supply the version numbers (and dates) for the files loaded by this example, it's likely that someone will recognize the problem.  without that information, we're just guessing.

Comment: Thank you all for very a quick response! I reinstalled everything (using MacTex, which I just discovered) and now it compiles properly.  The first problem, about hyperref getting confused in the Appendix, remains.  Perhaps I should post a MWE of that?  (Thanks for your patience, this is my first post!)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an out of date installation